# How to find the probability that both players take the same number of rounds in order to obtain their first lucky throws

Tags: probability, statistics

Two players each toss a pair of fair dice independently of one another until each makes a lucky throw, where a lucky throw is the one with the sum 7 or 11. Find the probability that the players take the same number of throws.

Please help me understand this problem.

Comment: Well, what's the probability that they both score on the first turn (or on any given turn)?

Comment: Unknown. We would need to know the rate of throwing dice. Example: Suppose one player begins a month before his opponent. From the wording of the problem, that player must continue throwing dice until the opponent also makes a lucky throw, so the first player could have thousands or even millions more throws than the opponent. Alternately, if a player throws dice until that player makes a lucky throw, the problem becomes much more straightforward, and it is as lulu suggests.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe: If you are determined not to understand something, you can always find a way. But it doesn't make you look clever.

Comment: @TonyK the point was not be to determined not to understand. The point was that mathematics requires precise language. The way the problem is worded, the interpretation I presented is a valid one. The phrase "until each makes a lucky throw" should be changed to something clarifying the actual stopping point. A single player rolls until they make a "lucky throw". I was not trying to be clever. I was trying to help the OP correct the language of the post to match the problem they are attempting to solve.

Comment: Well, the problem is correctly worded... One just needs to think deeply.

Comment: @HakimAsa That is false. The problem is demonstrably worded such that the example that I gave would be a valid interpretation of the problem as stated.

Comment: If you want I can share the book where the question was coined @InterstellarProbe

Comment: as I said it is correctly worded. No more argument, please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, each player independently throws $2$ dice until that player gets a lucky throw; then they compare the numbers of throws they took. This is equivalent to the players throwing dice simultaneously once per turn and stopping when at least one of them made a lucky throw, because then it's already certain that they'll need different numbers of throws.

The probability of throwing a $7$ or $11$ is $\frac29$. On any given turn, the probability that both make a lucky throw is $\left(\frac29\right)^2=\frac4{81}$. The probability that exactly one of them makes a lucky throw is $2\cdot\frac29\cdot\left(1-\frac29\right)=\frac{28}{81}$. Thus, conditional on the game ending in a given turn, the probability that it ends by both making a lucky draw is

$$
\frac{\frac4{81}}{\frac4{81}+\frac{28}{81}}=\frac18\;.
$$